# Spy on a non-default class export constructor with Jest

Tags: ts-jest

I'm trying to spy on a constructor that is being used in a function I'm testing. Inside my `createUpdatePermission` function, the following call is being made:

```typescript
const command = new UpdateCommand(input)
```

I want to spy on this constructor and run assertions based on the `input` it receives.

I've tried following the official [Jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports) on how to mock and spy on non-default class exports and created my test as follows:

```typescript
test('Should return an updated permission object', async () => {
  const mockDynamoResult = {
    Attributes: permissionMock
  }
  jest.mock('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb', () => {
    return {
      UpdateCommand: jest.fn().mockImplementation()
    }
  })
  jest.spyOn(DynamoDBDocumentClient.prototype, 'send').mockResolvedValue(mockDynamoResult as never)
  await Dynamo.createUpdatePermission(permissionMock)
  expect(UpdateCommand).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

This fails on the `expect(UpdateCommand).toHaveBeenCalled()` assertion with:

```
Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function UpdateCommand]
```

The Jest [complete example](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#complete-example) has very similar code, the only difference being that the module used in their example has a default export and the one I'm using (`@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb`) has not. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you solve this?